# ConcurrentHashSet against HashSet whose performance is better?

Tags: java

ConcurrentHashSet against HashSet whose performance is better in the concurrent environment?

```
//package com.google.code.yanf4j.util;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

/**
 * A {@link ConcurrentHashMap}-backed {@link Set}.
 * 
 * @author The Apache MINA Project (dev@mina.apache.org)
 * @version $Rev: 597692 $, $Date: 2007-11-23 08:56:32 -0700 (Fri, 23 Nov 2007)
 *          $
 */
public class ConcurrentHashSet<E> extends MapBackedSet<E> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8518578988740277828L;

  public ConcurrentHashSet() {
    super(new ConcurrentHashMap<E, Boolean>());
  }

  public ConcurrentHashSet(Collection<E> c) {
    super(new ConcurrentHashMap<E, Boolean>(), c);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(E o) {
    Boolean answer = ((ConcurrentMap<E, Boolean>) map).putIfAbsent(o,
        Boolean.TRUE);
    return answer == null;
  }
}
```

Comment: We are familiar with the Set implementations. No need to post the source code :-)

Comment: @Thihara this is ConcurrentHashSet and it is not in java api :)

Comment: What if you expanded upon your core need? You may, or may not, need a thread-safe implementation of a `Set`.

Comment: @fge yes I need thread-safe

Comment: Oops my bad... Still I stand by my answer... Because of the synchronization overhead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any environment `HashSet`'s performance will be better than `ConcurrentHashSet`. The problems will arise when concurrent writes and reads starts happening.

So for a concurrent environment best one is `ConcurrentHashSet`.

However if you are using the `HashSet` for storing some configurations that are loaded at startup only etc. (Only read operations occur after initial writes) it is OK. In my opinion...